# c++ map stl error : size of array 'apn2policy' has non-integral type 'const char [13]'

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following typedefs

```
struct PolicyRuleInfo{
    BearerQoSInfo stBearerQoS;
    TFTInfo stTFTInfo;

    PolicyRuleInfo(){};
    PolicyRuleInfo( BearerQoSInfo const& qos, TFTInfo const& tft)
       : stBearerQoS(qos), stTFTInfo(tft)
    { }
};

typedef map<string, PolicyRuleInfo> listOfPolicyRuleInfo;

struct IPAddressPolicyRulesInfo{
    CIPAddress ipAddress;
    listOfPolicyRuleInfo policyRules;
    IPAddressPolicyRulesInfo(){};
    IPAddressPolicyRulesInfo(CIPAddress ipaddr, string policyRuleName, PolicyRuleInfo policyRule): ipAddress(ipaddr){policyRules[policyRuleName]=policyRule;};

    void addPolicycyRule(string policyRuleName, PolicyRuleInfo policyRule) { policyRules[policyRuleName]=policyRule; }
};

typedef map<string, IPAddressPolicyRulesInfo> APN2PolicyRules;

typedef map<string, APN2PolicyRules>     IMSI2APNPolicyRules;
```

Later in a cpp:

```
u32 CPCRF::m_pNumPCCRulesViaCLI = 0;

listOfPolicyRuleInfo CPCRF::m_mlistOfCliConfiguredPolicyRules;

// map IMSI to PolicyRules
IMSI2APNPolicyRules         CPCRF::m_mIMSI2PCRFInfo;

// Assign some default Policies (Applicable to all subscribers) , can be changed via CLI
listOfPolicyRuleInfo m_mlistOfCliConfiguredPolicyRules = boost::assign::map_list_of("PolicyRule_Internet", PolicyRuleInfo( BearerQoSInfo(9), TFTInfo()))
                                                                                                                                         ("PolicyRule_Voice_C", PolicyRuleInfo( BearerQoSInfo(5), TFTInfo()))
                                                                                                                                         ("PolicyRule_Voice_U", PolicyRuleInfo( BearerQoSInfo(1), TFTInfo()));

    listOfPolicyRuleInfo::iterator it = m_mlistOfCliConfiguredPolicyRules.find("PolicyRule_Internet");

    if (it != m_mlistOfCliConfiguredPolicyRules.end() )
    {
        IMSI2APNPolicyRules::iterator itr= m_mIMSI2PCRFInfo.find(imsi);

        if (itr == m_mIMSI2PCRFInfo.end() )
        {
            IPAddressPolicyRulesInfo ipAddrPolicyRules(ueIPAddress, "PolicyRule_Internet", it->second);

            APN2PolicyRules apn2policy["Apn_Internet"]=ipAddrPolicyRules;

            m_mIMSI2PCRFInfo[imsi] = apn2policy;
```

I get the error saying that size of array 'apn2policy' has non-integral type 'const char [13]'

Earlier the I had declared listOfPolicyRuleInfo as typedef list, but when changed to map, I get this error.

thanks,
pdk

Comment: You couldn't construct a minimal testcase?

Comment: @Tomasz: APN2PolicyRules is a map type.

Comment: In short this will work:  apn2policy["Apn_Internet"]=ipAddrPolicyRules;

Comment: @pdk: Then why does your question not simply say `std::map<somekey, somevalue>`? Don't make us disentangle things.

Comment: @TomaszKłak: Please do not write answers as comments.

Comment: @pdk: Doesn't matter. Now you have an array of maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
APN2PolicyRules apn2policy["Apn_Internet"]=ipAddrPolicyRules;
```

This is wrong; you are declaring an array of `"Apn_Internet"` × `APN2PolicyRules` objects, which is clearly nonsense!

You must first create the map *then* use it:

```
APN2PolicyRules apn2policy; // (if it doesn't already exist)
apn2policy["Apn_Internet"] = ipAddrPolicyRules;
```

As you can see, the `Foo[Bar]` syntax means different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

`APN2PolicyRules apn2policy["Apn_Internet"]=ipAddrPolicyRules;`

This line is trying to declare an array of `APN2PolicyRules` but the size argument is a string literal which doesn't make any sense.

What you most likely meant to do is:

```
APN2PolicyRules apn2policy; // create map
apn2policy["Apn_Internet"]=ipAddrPolicyRules; // set rule
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit and Borgleader: I see that answer from Borgleader is 1 min before Lightness races. I see answers from Tomasz, and you both are correct. I am not sure which one to select. I donot want to be unfair though. Please help me with suggestions :)

Comment: @pdk: No, my answer was a minute before Borgleader's. He just copied mine! So accept mine :)